# web service being called twice with jquery ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the $.ajax function in jquery to make a call to an asmx service.  When I look at the requests from fiddler, I see two requests for each call I make.  One has a content type of text/html which of course returns a 401 not authorized status, and the other one has the correct content type and returns the correct data. Can anyone tell me why it is doing this and how I can fix it or if it needs fixing?

Comment: Can you post your client code?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is normal when you have anonymous requests disabled (you probably have Windows authentication enabled). The 401 is a challenge asking for the credentials.